# Redacting sensitive fields from Cloud Endpoints ESP Logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi, stackdriver

We are running App Engine Flexible behind Cloud Endpoints and have concerns about the ability to filter what is logged, does Cloud Endpoints offer ways to exclude fields on request data such as headers with API keys?

```
Current:
Client -> Endpoints -> App Engine 
                    -> Stackdriver Logging

Desired:
Client -> Endpoints -> App Engine 
                    -> Filtering -> Stackdriver Logging
```

As we don't have the ability to intercept the logging functionality I am not sure this is possible but others must also be aware this is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to exclude specific fields within Stackdriver Logging. If there are certain logs that you do not wish to have visible you can use log exclusion filters with the fields you are referring in order to omit those logs [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions#exclusions_in_the_api

Answer (score 0):

ESP doesn't log all headers in your request.  It only send limited info to stackdriver.  The code is [here](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/blob/master/src/api_manager/service_control/proto.cc#L1016)